# adding references in academic cv in "longtable class"

Tags: cv

I am trying to write my CV using the template given in

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/academic-cv-template/xykxmjmkxxjm

Please see the code below:

```
% Set document class and font size
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Package imports
\usepackage{setspace, longtable, graphicx, hyphenat, hyperref, fancyhdr, ifthen, everypage, enumitem, amsmath, setspace}

% --- Page layout settings ---

% Set page margins
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, bottom=0.7in, top=0.7in]{geometry}

% Set line spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}

% --- Page formatting ---

% Set link colors
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=RoyalBlue, urlcolor=RoyalBlue}

% Set font to Libertine, including math support
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

% Remove page numbering
\pagenumbering{gobble}

% --- Document starts here ---

\begin{document}

% Name and date of last update to this document
\noindent{\Huge{Your name here}
\hfill{\it\footnotesize Updated \today}}

% --- Contact information and other items ---

\vspace{0.5cm} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
% Line 1: Email, GitHub, office location
\textbf{Email}: email@cornell.edu      &
\hspace{0.55in} \textbf{GitHub}: //github-username    &
\hspace{0.4in}  \textbf{Office}: Your Building 101 \\

% Line 2: Phone number, LinkedIn, citizenship
\textbf{Phone}: (314) 159-2654   & 
\hspace{0.55in} \textbf{LinkedIn}: //LinkedIn-URL   & 
\hspace{0.4in} \textbf{Citizenship}: Country 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

% --- Start the two-column table storing the main content ---

% Set spacing between columns
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}

% Set the width of each column
\begin{longtable}{p{1.3in}p{4.8in}}


\color{OliveGreen}{Service and outreach}
& \textbf{Title of organization you were in} \hfill Month Year -- Month Year \\
& Description of your responsibilities. Integer pretium semper justo. Proin risus. Aliquam volutpat est vel massa. \\
& \\



\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

There is no option to add reference letter writers' details.

Can someone kindly tell me how to add those details?

I want to make it look like the following:

[image]

I was trying to use \hspace to put appropriate gap but it is not aligning well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I won't go to an external site to debug your code. Such links will be invalid at some time and make your question useless for other users. Provide a small but complete example that demonstrates your problem here.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have added the sample code. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: How do you expect the "reference letter writers' details" to look like? Please prepare a sketch of the expected output.

Comment: @leandriis I have added it. Please see :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `tabular*` inside of the second column of the longtable:

[image]

```
% Set document class and font size
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Package imports
\usepackage{setspace, longtable, graphicx, hyphenat, hyperref, fancyhdr, ifthen, everypage, enumitem, amsmath, setspace}
\usepackage{array}
% --- Page layout settings ---

% Set page margins
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, bottom=0.7in, top=0.7in]{geometry}

% Set line spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}

% --- Page formatting ---

% Set link colors
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=RoyalBlue, urlcolor=RoyalBlue}

% Set font to Libertine, including math support
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

% Remove page numbering
\pagenumbering{gobble}

% --- Document starts here ---

\begin{document}

% Name and date of last update to this document
\noindent{\Huge{Your name here}
\hfill{\it\footnotesize Updated \today}}

% --- Contact information and other items ---

\vspace{0.5cm} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
% Line 1: Email, GitHub, office location
\textbf{Email}: email@cornell.edu      &
\hspace{0.55in} \textbf{GitHub}: //github-username    &
\hspace{0.4in}  \textbf{Office}: Your Building 101 \\

% Line 2: Phone number, LinkedIn, citizenship
\textbf{Phone}: (314) 159-2654   & 
\hspace{0.55in} \textbf{LinkedIn}: //LinkedIn-URL   & 
\hspace{0.4in} \textbf{Citizenship}: Country 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

% --- Start the two-column table storing the main content ---

% Set spacing between columns
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}

% Set the width of each column
\begin{longtable}{>{\color{OliveGreen}}p{1.3in}p{4.8in}}


Service and outreach
& \textbf{Title of organization you were in} \hfill Month Year -- Month Year \\
& Description of your responsibilities. Integer pretium semper justo. Proin risus. Aliquam volutpat est vel massa. \\
& \\

References
& \begin{tabular*}{\hsize}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll} Name 1 & Name 2\\ Address 1 & Address 2 \\ email address 1 & email address 2 \end{tabular*}
 \\




\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked smoothly.